# php foreach loop display all data

Tags: php, foreach

I have dump problem with foreach loop... 
I want to display all data in foreach, example:

```
$data[1] = "Hello"; 
$data[2] = "my"; 
$data[3] = "World";
```

I use this script and work

```
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
        $mydata = $data[$i];
        echo $mydata; }
```

This is ok, no problem. 
But when I want to include $mydata in next script (for saving in txt), he shows only the last word, *World*

Why? How to include all data from variable

Comment: `$i<3` should be `$i<=3` if you have an id of `3` like `$data[3] = "World";`.... or just use a `foreach()` loop.... [so it shouldn't work ok for that loop](https://3v4l.org/8Gt0d)

Comment: You can directly concatenate all values by some characters using the `implode` method in [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$mydata = '';
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
   $mydata .= $data[$i];
}
echo $mydata;
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you are overwriting the variable `$mydata` and your are print that one so it replacing each time, you can store that into array and dump that variable after loop ended,

```
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
    $mydata[] = $data[$i];
    echo $data[$i]; 
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($mydata)

# You can directly dump the all the variable as follow
echo implode('\n', $mydate) 
# or
echo implode('\n', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just `echo`ed `$mydata` inside for loop so it will print the value as of last occurrence value as you are **changing/overriding** the `$mydata` variable value.

Use like this:

```
$mydata = '';//Storing $mydata variable
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
  $mydata .= $data[$i]; //adding up the values to $mydata
}
var_dump($mydata); //dumps all the $data value.
```